# C project with files

Tags: c, file, input, file-io, output

I need some help with my C project:
I need to write a c program who receives 2 parameters:

1) The name of a text file(infile) which is in the same catalog

2) A number k>0
And creates 2 new files,outfile1 & outfile 2 as:

Outfile 1: k,2*k,3*k…. character of infile

Outfile 2: k,2*k,3*k…..line of infile

Example:

INFILE

```
Abcdefg
123456
XXXXXX
01010101
```

OUTFILE 1:

```
Cf25XX101
```

OUTFILE 2:

```
XXXXXX
```

I wrote some code ,but its not working. Any ideas?

```
 #include <stdio.h>      
 #include <stdlib.h>     
 #include <string.h>     


char** read_lines(FILE* txt, int* count) {
    char** array = NULL;        
    int    i;                   
    char   line[100];           
    int    line_count;          
    int    line_length;         
    *count = 0;                 
    line_count = 0;              
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), txt) != NULL) {                                      
       line_count++;
    }
    rewind(txt);                
    array = malloc(line_count * sizeof(char *));    
    if (array == NULL) {
        return NULL;                                
    }
     for (i = 0; i < line_count; i++) {             
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), txt);             
        line_length = strlen(line);                 
        line[line_length - 1] = '\0';
        line_length--;                              
        array[i] = malloc(line_length + 1);         
        strcpy(array[i], line);                    
    }
    *count = line_count;                           
    return array;                                  
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char**      array    = NULL;    
    FILE*       file     = NULL;    
    const char* filename = NULL;    
    int         i;                  
    int         line_count;         
    int         k;                  
    char        c;                  
    printf("ENTER ONE PHYSICAL NUMBER\n");         
    do{                                            
        if(k>0)
            scanf("%d",&k);

        else{
            printf("ENTER ONE PHYSICAL NUMBER\n");
            scanf("%d",&k);
        }
    }while(k<=0);
    file = fopen("LEIT.txt", "rt"); 
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("CANT OPEN FILE %s.\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
     array = read_lines(file, &line_count);   
     printf("ARRAY:\n");
     for (i = 0; i < line_count; i++) {       
        printf("[%d]: %s\n", (i+1), array[i]);
    }
    printf("CALCULATING OUTFILE1 AND OUTFILE2\n");
    printf("OUTFILE1:\n");
    for(i=0;i<line_count;i++){              
        c=i*k;                              
        printf("%c\n",array[c]);              
    }
    printf("WRITING OUTFILE1 COMPLETE!\n");

    printf("OUTFILE2:\n");
    for(i=0;i<line_count;i++){              
        c=i*k;                                
        printf("%c\n",array[c]);             
    }
    printf("WRITING OUTFILE2 COMPLETE!\n"); 

    return 0;

}
```

My actual problem is calculate and write into files (outfile1 and outfile2) the result...

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to close file after finishing reading/writing it with `fclose`.
2. You can create and write strings to a file using `fopen` with correct mode.
3. You can output formatted string to a file by using `fprintf`.
4. It seems that you don't want to print the 0th character/line, so in the last `for` loop, `i` should start from 1 (or start from 0 but add 1 later).
5. `array[c]` is a string, not a character. So when printing it, you should use `%s` specifier instead of `%c`.
6. It is not a good idea using `char` as count in later `for` loops unless you know input file will be very short. `signed char` can only count to 127 before overflow (`unsigned char` can count to 255). But if you have a very long file, for example thousands of lines, this program would not work properly.
7. `array` is malloced in function `char** read_lines(FILE* txt, int* count)`. After finish using it, you need to dealloc, or free it by calling

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < line_count; i++) {
       free(array[i]);
   }
   ```

   and followed by `free(array)`. This avoids memory leakage.

Modified code is here. In the following code, `char c` is not used. This is the part where you process output files, and before `return 0;` in main function.

```
    printf("CALCULATING OUTFILE1 AND OUTFILE2\n");
    printf("OUTFILE1:\n");

    // Since we finished using LEIT.txt, close it here.
    fclose(file);

    // Mode: "w" - Write file. "+" - Create if not exist.
    // You can lso use "a+" (append file) here if previous record need to be preserved.
    FILE *out1 = fopen("OUTFILE1.txt", "w+");
    FILE *out2 = fopen("OUTFILE2.txt", "w+");

    if ((out1 == NULL) || (out2 == NULL)) {
        printf("CANT CREATE OUTPUT FILES.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Out file 1.
    unsigned int count = k;

    for (i = 0; i < line_count; i++){
        while (count < strlen(array[i])) {
            // This just prints to stdout, but is good for debug.
            printf("%c", array[i][count]);

            // Write to the file.
            fprintf(out1, "%c", array[i][count]);

            // Calculate c for next char.
            count += k + 1;
        }

        // Before go to next line, minus string length of current line.
        count -= strlen(array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("WRITING OUTFILE1 COMPLETE!\n");

    // Close file.
    fclose(out1);

    // Out file 2.
    printf("OUTFILE2:\n");

    for (i = 1;i < line_count / k; i++){
        count = i * k;

        // This just prints to stdout, but is good for debug.
        printf("%s\n", array[count]);

        // Write to the file.
        fprintf(out2, "%s\n", array[count]);
    }
    printf("WRITING OUTFILE2 COMPLETE!\n");

    //Close file.
    fclose(out2);

    // dealloc malloced memory.
    for (i = 0; i < line_count; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
```